# Get array from database, using one of the columns as array key

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a function like this to get users from a database:

```
function getUsers(){
    $db = db::getInstance();
    $res = $db->prepare("
        SELECT *
        FROM `users`
        ORDER BY `points` DESC
    ");
    $res->execute();
    if($res->rowCount()==0){
        return null;
    }
    return $res->fetchAll();
}
```

This will return an array like:

```
Array(
    0 => {id => 555, name => Smith, firstname => William, points => 123}
    1 => {id => 213, name => Hitchcock, firstname => Alfred, points => 95}
    2 => {id => 999, name => James, firstname => Kevin, points => 66}
)
```

Is there a simple way to use one of the fields as key? In this example I might want the field `id` to be used as array keys, so I would want this result:

```
Array(
    555 => {id => 555, name => Smith, firstname => William, points => 123}
    213 => {id => 213, name => Hitchcock, firstname => Alfred, points => 95}
    999 => {id => 999, name => James, firstname => Kevin, points => 66}
)
```

I could achieve this by manually creating a new result array like:

```
    $result = [];
    foreach($res->fetchAll() as $row){
        $result[$row['id']] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
```

Does PHP or PDO provide a built-in solution for this though? I'm trying to keep the complexity (as in speed/memory usage) as low as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fetch mode `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE`:

```
return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

Note that this will use the first column from the SELECT as array index and remove that column from the row. If you want to keep that column (`id`) you will need to select it twice:

```
function getUsers(){
    $db = db::getInstance();
    $res = $db->query("
        SELECT u.id as unique_key, u.*
        FROM `users` u
        ORDER BY `points` DESC
    ");
    if($res->rowCount()==0){
        return null;
    }
    return $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Just to add: `as unique_key` was not neccessary, it seems to work flawless even without that part.